# Display related product based in custom taxonomy Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to override the related products of Woocommerce to related product based on a custom taxonomy.  I added a custom taxonomy called vendor name and wanted to show related products that only belong or have the same vendor name or ID. I tried this but I am getting no result for some reason.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', function( $args ) 
{
global $post, $wpdb, $woocommerce;
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'vendor_name', array("fields" => "ids"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
$vendor_id = $term_single->ID; 
}

unset( $args['post__in'] );
$args['tax_query'] = array(
'taxonomy' => 'vendor_name',
'field'    => 'term_id',
'terms'    => $vendor_id

 );
return $args;
});
```

Comment: Please print_r($term_list); and see what results you get.

Comment: it shows Array ( )